# Jquery UI Date Picker With Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a bootstrap site and I'm using Jquery UI datapickers for one section.  The problem is, the only way that seems to work to get the date picker open when a button is clicked is to initialize it with a  button that Jquery Chooses in the datepicker function.

I would ideally like to use the Append with Button style but I can't seem to find a way to hard code it so that the button is just hard coded as opposed to generated dynamically.

Is there an easy way to do this without changing the source code for JQuery UI?

## Edit

```
<div class="input-append span2">
     <input type="text" id="datestart" class="datepicker input-small"/>
     <input type="button" class="ui-date-pickertrigger"/>
  </div>
  <div class="input-append">
     <input type="text" id="dateend" class="datepicker input-small"/>
     <input type="button" class="ui-date-pickertrigger"/>
  </div>
```

Then Initialized with

```
$(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();  
});
```

Comment: Please post the code you've tried and/or an example on a site like jsFiddle.net

Comment: @j08691 +1 :). MobyD is these are what you're looking for ? http://aymkdn.github.com/Datepicker-for-Bootstrap/ https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: Pretty much that max max.  But I prefer the JQuery UI's interpretation more and will use that library only when I'm sufficiently frustrated.

Comment: https://jasenhk.wordpress.com/2013/03/09/jquery-datepicker-with-bootstrap-icon/